# Реквизит "Ссылка" у справочников и документов

Tags: 1с

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем смысл стандартного реквизита "Ссылка" у справочников и документов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из справки:

**СправочникСсылка.<Имя справочника>**

*Описание:*

Используется для указания ссылки на элемент справочника в реквизитах других объектов и переменных встроенного языка. Данный объект не содержит средств для чтения, изменения, добавления и удаления элемента справочника, однако позволяет обращаться к его реквизитам и другой информации об элементе. При обращении к свойствам объекта будет выполняться считывание всех данных элемента справочника из базы данных, но оно будет оптимизировано при многократном обращении к данному элементу как через этот объект, так и через другое равное ему значение.

Comment: Yura Ivanov, а реквизит "Ссылка" и СправочникСсылка.<Имя справочника> это одно и то же?

Comment: @leklerk реквизит у справочников Ссылка имеет тип СправочникСсылка, у документов ДокументСсылка бывают еще ссылки для Перечисление, Задача, ПланСчетов, ПланВидовХарактеристик, БизнесПроцесс... У каждого типа свои методы и функции, но принцип у всех одинаковый - ссылка на объект конфигурации.

Comment: Спасибо, понял. :) Скажите, а где можно прочитать, что реквизит у справочников Ссылка имеет тип СправочникСсылка (в документации или где-нибудь еще?). Я нигде не нашел... Интуитивно понимаю, что это верно, но просто интересно, ГДЕ это написано? :)

Comment: F1 - справка. Ctrl-F1 контекстная справка. а вообще есть литература по 1С... стоит ее почитать.